# How do I control the automatic scroll when text field focus change on flutter

Tags: flutter

I had to put this area with a button upper the keyboard because number keyboard on iOS does not have a “done” button as the normal keyboard. So, in android it works properly like this:

[Change focus working on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXD9R.gif)

Now, on iOS it works like this:

[Change focus working on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epOUK.gif)

As you can see in the gif the field is being overlaid by that area with a button. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of managing keyboard manually, I would like to suggest you to use [keyboard_actions](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions) package.

Here are the key features of the same

- Done button for the keyboard ( You can customize the button).
- Move up/down between your Textfields.
- Keyboard Bar customization.
- Custom footer widget below keyboard bar
- You can use it for Android, iOS or both platforms.
- Compatible with Dialog.

> Got Reference from [this](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions)